# Reasonable backoff algorithm?

Tags: security

I'd like to slow down attackers who would brute force parts of my app that leak account information. (For example, if you hit the sign up page with an in-use user id, the page response tells you that user id would be good to subsequently dictionary attack.)

What's an appropriate **algorithm** to make successive failed attempts **slower and slower**?  Real-world example would be successive bad passwords on an iPhone.

I'm implementing in PHP, but any pseudocode response would be appreciated.  The critical part of the answer is:

On bad try N, delay the response by X.

And a really great answer would incorporate:

M tries is within our tolerance for human errors, so the curve "hockey sticks" near M+1

Answer (score 0):

Simple geometric feels **too draconian** for people that have, for example, common names.  (John Smith might need a few tries to find an unoccupied user id.)

`sleep(pow(2,$failed_attempts));`

Maybe I'm picking a silly constant?